# Read the (properly formatted) contents of a file using MSBuild

Tags: file-io, msbuild

I am attempting to dynamically generate a SQL script using MSBuild. The script is responsible for updating some tables etc... post-build.

One of the requirements of this script is to retrieve the product's release notes from a text file and place them into an insert statement in the SQL script.

I'm using TemplateFile to replace the values in a template and generate the SQL script, and it's working as expected. My problem begins when I attempt to read the release notes file. The following is my code:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SQLFileTemplate>Update Product Table.template</SQLFileTemplate>
    <SQLFileName>Update Product Table.sql</SQLFileName>     
    <ReleaseNotesFile>Release Notes.txt</ReleaseNotesFile>
</PropertyGroup>

<ReadLinesFromFile File="$(ReleaseNotesFile)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="FileContents" />
</ReadLinesFromFile>

<ItemGroup>
    <Tokens Include="releaseDate">
        <ReplacementValue>$(buildDate)</ReplacementValue>
    </Tokens>
    <Tokens Include="releaseNotes">
        <!--Escape the CR LF because MSBuild will replace them with semicolon-->
        <ReplacementValue>@(FileContents, '%0a%0d')</ReplacementValue>
    </Tokens>
    <Tokens Include="releaseLevel">
        <ReplacementValue>0</ReplacementValue>
    </Tokens>
    <Tokens Include="currentVersionInts">
        <ReplacementValue>@(versionInts)</ReplacementValue>
    </Tokens>
    <Tokens Include="currentVersion">
        <ReplacementValue>$(GuiVersion)</ReplacementValue>
    </Tokens>
    <Tokens Include="productVersionId"> 
        <ReplacementValue>$(productId)</ReplacementValue>
    </Tokens>
</ItemGroup>    

<TemplateFile Template="$(SQLFileTemplate)" OutputFileName="$(SQLFileName)" Tokens="@(Tokens)" />
```

When I do this, the file is read but it's just put into single spacing and the format is completely gone. I've looked at ReadTextFromFile in MSBuild.Community.Tasks.FileSystem but I can't figure out the syntax.

Can someone give me a hand for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you trying to replace tokens in a file? I don't think you need to go through read and write the file. 
You can use the detokenise task in the extension pack to achieve the same results. See: http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.4.0/index.html

Although i do use the community tasks I think the extension pack has a lot more to offer than the community tasks.

Comment: I looked at the documentation for Detokenise and I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for... How does it read the release notes from the file? I need to essentially take the (exact) contents of the release notes file and place them into the SQL script, replacing the releaseNotes token in the SQL Script template (which I've defined).

Comment: Then im not much help. The detokonise is good for ordinary token replacement, but add merging in a file is a different problem. Good luck. It would just be a different way of doing the same thing. I have had some problems from readlinesfromfile when the file encoding where mixed up unicode and utf-8.